# keep bootstrap less small

Tags: less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a project based on twitter bootstrap 3 and I'm using the LESS file from bootstrap to take advantage of the mixins and breakpoint variables (like `@screen-md`).

In my own style.less file I imported:

```
@import "../less/bootstrap.less";
```

When I look at the output (style.css) there are more than 6000 rows. Is there a way to use the mixins from bootstrap 3, whilst still keeping an economic file size?

Comment: Mixins themselves are not output to the CSS file. You *can* just include individual components of bootstrap, did you try that? Can you clarify what you're after?

Comment: In order to use the mixins, I needed to import them. I did this by importing the bootstrap.less file. The result was a pretty huge css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Now Available in LESS 1.5

You can import a file just for reference purposes, so:

```
@import (reference) "../less/bootstrap.less";
```

Will give you access to the mixins without actually including the code in your output css.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap.less contains all other imports make your style.less like:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
// your styles here
```

NOTE when you import bootstrap.less in your style.less you will compile bootstrap + your styles

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer, works like a charm. I ended up with importing the variables.less, mixins.less and responsive-utilities.less. Result is 10 times smaller then the big bootstrap.less.

Answer (score 0):

You can import only those LESS bootstrap files that you need.

`bootstrap.less` itself imports **all** other LESS files, that's why output is so huge.

Take a detailed look at the contents of 'less' directory.
The files you're looking for are probably `mixins.less` and `variables.less`.

Comment: thanks as well, as said in reply to Bass, it works by only importing the needed less files.